# ¿porqué le pasa esto a mi cuadro de color?

Tags: css, google-chrome, html-select

Cuando le disminuyo el tamaño a la página, el cuadro se mueve y queda más arriba de lo que debería. ya lo he intentado con todos el -display- posible.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como ven, el cuadro se va hacia arriba (debería de estar abajo).

Este es el código:

```css
.country {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #F2F2F2;
  color: #70757a;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: justify;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20.8%;
  display: block;
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  width: 75vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 350px;
  max-width: 560px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="country">Colombia</div>
  <div class="final">
    <div class="f">
      <a class="in" href="https://about.google/?utm_source=google-CO&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=hp-footer&fg=1"> About</a>
      <a class="in" href="https://ads.google.com/intl/en_co/home/?subid=ww-ww-et-g-awa-a-g_hpafoot1_1!o2&utm_source=google.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=google_hpafooter&fg=1"> Advertising</a>
      <a class="in" href="https://smallbusiness.withgoogle.com/intl/es-419_co/help/#!/"> Business</a>
      <a class="in" href="https://www.google.com/search/howsearchworks/?fg=1" ; style="word-spacing: 3px;"> How Search Works</a>
    </div>
    <div class="fd">
      <a href="https://policies.google.com/privacy?hl=en-CO&fg=1"> Privacy</a>
      <a href="https://policies.google.com/terms?hl=en-CO&fg=1"> Terms</a>
    </div>
    <button class="sett">settings</button>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Y este es el de abajo que tiene el "About".

Si me pueden ayudar a que no se corra hacia arriba se los agradecería, gracias.

Comment: Hola, Emily. Bienvenida a Stack Overflow. Debes compartir el código HTML que has escrito, porque es importante analizar su estructura. Otra cosa, no te olvides hacer [tour] para que conozcas cómo funciona el sitio y ganes tu primera medalla.

Comment: La propiedad wrap es para que los items flex se vayan apilando cuando la ventana se achica. Ponle no wrap

Comment: hola Hernán. ya le agregué el no wrap y se sigue subiendo ¿Qué más podría hacer?

Comment: al `class="country"` le estas aplicando dos veces una propiedad `display`, intenta quitando el `display: block;` del final.

Comment: creo que falta el CSS del About, Advertising...

Answer (score 0):

El tema es que le estas poniendo el `margin-top` en porcentajes a la clase `.country` sácale ese porcentaje y siempre va a quedar abajo de todo y obvio vale aclarar que a medida que le insertes contenido al `body` el `footer` va ir bajando.

```css
.country {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #F2F2F2;
  color: #70757a;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: justify;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  width: 75vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 350px;
  max-width: 560px;
}
```

```html
  <p>header</p>
  <p>body</p>
  <p>body</p>
  <p>body</p>
  <p>body</p>
  <p>body</p>
  <p>body</p>
  <p>body</p>
  <p>body</p>
  <p>body</p>
  <p>body</p>
  <p>body</p>
  <p>body</p>
  <p>body</p>
  <p>body</p>
  <p>body</p>
  <p>body</p>

  <footer>
    <div class="country">Colombia</div>
    <div class="final">
      <div class="f">
        <a class="in" href="https://about.google/?utm_source=google-CO&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=hp-footer&fg=1"> About</a>
        <a class="in" href="https://ads.google.com/intl/en_co/home/?subid=ww-ww-et-g-awa-a-g_hpafoot1_1!o2&utm_source=google.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=google_hpafooter&fg=1"> Advertising</a>
        <a class="in" href="https://smallbusiness.withgoogle.com/intl/es-419_co/help/#!/"> Business</a>
        <a class="in" href="https://www.google.com/search/howsearchworks/?fg=1" ; style="word-spacing: 3px;"> How Search Works</a>
      </div>
      <div class="fd">
        <a href="https://policies.google.com/privacy?hl=en-CO&fg=1"> Privacy</a>
        <a href="https://policies.google.com/terms?hl=en-CO&fg=1"> Terms</a>
      </div>
      <button class="sett">settings</button>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

Espero ayudarte con esto, cualquier cosa me comentas, Suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias Daniel, ahora el cuadro no se mueve.